# How to filter columns based on values in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to delete all the rows that have a last value of zero and all the columns that have a final value of zero.

This a dummy (reproducible) example of my dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

x = c("apples" ,1,0,1,2)
y = c("bananas",0,0,0,0)
z = c("apples" ,2,0,4,6)
t = c("rowsum" ,3,0,5,8)

my_table = rbind(x,y,z,t)
colnames(my_table) = c("product","day1","day2","day3","colsum")

my_table = as.tbl(as.data.frame(my_table)) %>% 
  mutate(day1 = as.integer(as.character(day1)),
         day2 = as.integer(as.character(day2)),
         day3 = as.integer(as.character(day3)),
         colsum = as.integer(as.character(colsum)))
```

The dummy example has this output:

```
> my_table
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  product  day1  day2  day3 colsum
   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
1  apples     1     0     1      2
2 bananas     0     0     0      0
3  apples     2     0     4      6
4  rowsum     3     0     5      8
```

Now I remove the rows with a final value of zero:

```
my_table = my_table %>% 
  filter(colsum > 0)

> my_table
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  product  day1  day2  day3 colsum
   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
1  apples     1     0     1      2
2  apples     2     0     4      6
3  rowsum     3     0     5      8
```

The question is:

### **How to filter columns based on values in `dplyr`?**

I want to  do something like this:

```
# code that does NOT work
my_table = my_table %>% 
  filter(my_table[nrow(my_table)] > 0)
```

To obtain:

```
> my_table
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  product  day1  day3 colsum
   <fctr> <int> <int>  <int>
1  apples     1     1      2
2  apples     2     4      6
3  rowsum     3     5      8
```

**Update: 
Solution by @Patronius (works with `dplyr 0.5.0`)**

```
my_table %>% 
  filter(colsum > 0) %>% 
  select_if(function(.) last(.) != 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  product  day1  day3 colsum
   <fctr> <int> <int>  <int>
1  apples     1     1      2
2  apples     2     4      6
3  rowsum     3     5      8
```

Comment: Do you mean filter **columns** rather than rows? (If so, do you mean you want to remove any that are entirely zero?)

Comment: exactly, so to remove both columns and rows that are null

Comment: Your title and bolded statement both say "How to filter rows"- do you want to edit them?

Comment: thanks !! I didn't notice that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use dplyr's `select_if` and `last`:

```
my_table %>%
  select_if(function(.) last(.) != 0)
```

Note that it kept the factor column `product` (since it's not true that the last item of the `product` factor is zero).

Comment: I did that but I get
`Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'p' of mode 'function' was not found`

Comment: @pachamaltese Could you use `sessionInfo()` and let me know the version of dplyr you're working with?

Comment: @pachamaltese As one experiment, could you please try `select_if(function(.) last(.) != 0)` instead? It's possible the formula interface got added more recently.

Comment: what the ... yes, that works unlike older posts that I read :S

Comment: @pachamaltese Cool! I think the formula interface is only in the development version (soon to be released as 0.6.0). I've edited the answer accordingly