# Identifying rows with values equal to 0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I'm trying to find a way to identify columns within a data frame that have any entries equal to 0. If that particular column has a value equal to 0, I would like to create a new data frame without the columns that contain a zero value. In addition, I would like to create a list of the columns retained and the columns removed.

```
Example:

    dataframe1:

Column1       Column2     Column3     Column4
    .03           .05         .07         .08
    .01           .09         .22         .39
      0           .56         .88         .56

    dataframe2:

Column1       Column2     Column3     Column4
    .03           .05         .07         .08
    .01           .09         .22         .39
      0           .56         .88         .56

   retainedColumns = 2, 3, 4
   removedColumns = 1
```

I figured this could be done in dplyr easily. 
As for creating a new data frame, my attempt at the code (keeps crashing):

```
dataframe2<-dataframe1[!dataframe1 %in% 0, ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pierre Lapointe's answer is excellent. The answer to [How to filter columns based on values in dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725669/how-to-filter-columns-based-on-values-in-dplyr) shows a dplyr solution as well:    df2 <- df %>% select_if(function(.) last(.) != 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following. Basically, you are summing the number of zeroes in each columns with `colSums(df==0)`. The `!` before excludes all columns that do not have a sum of zeroes equal to 0.

```
df[!colSums(df==0)]

  Column2 Column3 Column4
1    0.05    0.07    0.08
2    0.09    0.22    0.39
3    0.56    0.88    0.56
```

And here's how to get a list of columns retained and removed:

```
retainedColumns <- which(!colSums(df==0)) 
#Column2 Column3 Column4 
#  2       3       4 

removedColumns <- which(colSums(df==0) > 0)
#Column1 
#  1 

#A double negation (!!) would also work here:
removedColumns <- which(!!colSums(df==0))
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text="Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
.03 .05 .07 .08
0 .09 .22 .39
0 .56 .88 .56", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```